# Custom Permalink with Page Name Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, url, mod-rewrite, permalinks

I have looked all over the place and can't figure out how to get this to work.

I want my urls for blog posts to look like this: "www.website.com/my-page/category-name/blog-post-title"

The issue I am having is that I have a page called "my-page".

So I have a page "www.website.com/my-page/" which is just a standard wordpress page, but I want the url for the blog post to look like it is under that page.

Here is what I have for the permalink so far:

```
/my-page/%category%/%postname%/
```

But this doesn't work and gets a 404 error when opening a blog post.

At this point I don't believe it can be fixed through the wordpress gui, so if anyone has any recommendations, it would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Edit: I wanted to add that the permalink works fine if I remove "/my-page" or if I simply modify it so it does not match the page.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should not use the category in front of your permalinks as it leads to bad performance (and some posts may have multiple categories): http://ottopress.com/2010/category-in-permalinks-considered-harmful/

The second thing is - it should work.  I tried with a fresh installation on WordPress and I get the correct results.

- Did you flush rewrite rules / save the new permalink structure?
- Did you publish a post?
- Is your server correctly configured to use permalinks?

Third possibility - if your permalink structure does not work for some reason you can define a custom permalink structure:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API

Comment: I could not get it to work on a fresh install, are you sure there is a matching page with the same slug as in the permalink? And yes, if I simply remove the "/my-page" it works fine, it is only when that part matches a page on the site which causes the error.

Also, thanks for the info about the bad performance, that is good to know, however, for my specific purpose, I need it that way.

Comment: Ok I see the problem now this is a bit more tricky. What you could try to do is to modify the permalink rewrite rules according to the WordPress rewrite API so that your custom rewrite rule has a higher priority than the matching of the page.